# Insert multiple values into table structure based on case/when statement

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the need to do this.

```
Declare @something varchar(100)
Declare @tempdata TABLE (temp varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @tempdata (temp) select case 
       when @something is null then 'temp1','temp2'
       else @something
       end

select * from @tempdata
```

Looks like inserting multiple values into the @tempdata array based on when condition is null, is not valid.

How do I add multiple values to @tempdata when @something is not set.

I tried doing this

```
when @something is null then 'temp1,temp2'
```

and then tried to split it by delimiter comma and then add to @tempdata, but splitting in sql doesn't look easy.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You're probably best off splitting each of your cases up into an `if`-`else` structure.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. and it worked. Is there a way for the above to work in a case..when statement. Just curios now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `IF` statement, followed by inserting with a `SELECT... UNION ALL`.

```
Declare @something varchar(100)
Declare @tempdata TABLE (temp varchar(100))

IF @something is null
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempdata (temp)
    SELECT 'temp1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'temp2'
END

select * from @tempdata
```